# WriteConf of Spark-Cassandra Connector being used or not

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, batch-processing, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark version 1.6.2, Spark-Cassandra Connector 1.6.0, Cassandra-Driver-Core 3.0.3

I am writing a simple Spark job in which I am trying to insert some rows to a table in Cassandra. The code snippet used was:

```
val sparkConf = (new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<Cassandra IP>")
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "test")
.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "test")
.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "1"))

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val cassandraSQLContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
cassandraSQLContext.setKeyspace("test")
val query = "select * from test"
val dataRDD = cassandraSQLContext.cassandraSql(query).rdd

val addRowList = (ListBuffer(
Test(111, 10, 100000, "{'test':'0','test1':'1','others':'2'}"),
Test(111, 20, 200000, "{'test':'0','test1':'1','others':'2'}")
))

val insertRowRDD = sc.parallelize(addRowList)
insertRowRDD.saveToCassandra("test", "test")
```

Test() is a case class

Now, I have passed the WriteConf parameter output.batch.size.rows when making sparkConf object. I am expecting that this code will write 1 row in a batch at a time in Cassandra. I am not getting any method through which I can cross verify that the configuration of writing a batch in cassandra is not the default one but the one passed in the code snippet.

I could not find anything in the cassandra cassandra.log, system.log and debug.log

So can anyone help me with the method of cross verifying the WriteConf being used by Spark-Cassandra Connector to write batches in Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to verify that your setting was correctly set.

1. First you can call the method which creates WriteConf

   ```
   WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sparkConf)
   ```

   The resulting object can be inspected to make sure all the values are what you want. This is the default arg to [SaveToCassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/4da9a0bf180dc6035f45bc58c3439dab5605ccc0/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala#L87)
2. You can explicitly pass a `WriteConf` to the `saveToCassandraMethod`

   ```
   saveAsCassandraTable(keyspace, table, writeConf = WriteConf(...))
   ```

Comment: Not sure how to call `saveToCassandraTable` with `WriteConf`, looks like it overrides settings from `SparkConf`. How can I set specific parameters while inheriting the rest from the Spark?

Comment: WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sparkConf).copy(parameterToChange = newValue)

Comment: Hah! case class `copy` just added to my Scala lexicon! Thanks :)

Comment: @RussS I'm trying to use rdd's to set row level ttl in a c* table. I'm setting all the connection information in spark conf and passing ttl option in writeconf like below:
rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table, writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.perRow(ttlColumn)))
but the config is not honoring the cassandra cluster config. any idea how I can send both the information in writeconf or how can I set ttl in spark conf and send that spark conf to rdd.saveTocassandra. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand, could you ask a new SO question and please include examples of your code